# How to transfer my Dump(.sql) file on server?

Tags: mysql

I have created a dump file for my database and now I want to put that
file on my server to get its access. I will copy that `.sql` file on my
server, but I don't know how to access that dump file using commands.

Comment: That means, you have backup file on your local machine and want to put it on remote server for restoring it there, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using command line

```
cd /path/where/sql/file/is
```

And then

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

If you don't have the mysql bin in your PATH you might want to run

```
/path/to/mysql/bin/mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Or temporarily put the file.sql in the mysql bin directory (not recommended)

Another possible scenario is to point to the file in the filesystem like this

```
mysql -u username -p database_name < /path/where/sql/file/is/file.sql
```

If you're on windows you might wanna change the forward slashes to backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **restore MySQL database on remote-server**, then very first thing is that, the `.sql` file is not necessarily present on server.

We can restore the backup right from our development machine(using `mysql.exe` of local machine), provided that you have MySQL user having MySQL Server remote access.

Use "**-h**" option while restoring the backup. "**-h**" implies **hostname** where MySQL Database Server is present. It can be in local network or on remote server.

```
mysql -h www.yourserver.com -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Or with IP Address (use actual IP Address of your Database Server)

```
mysql -h 112.112.112.112 -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

And if you do not have remote-access enabled user, then you need to upload `.sql` file to remote-server and restore it by putting `host-name` as `localhost`. Like,

```
mysql -h localhost -u username -p database_name < file.sql
```

Hope it helps, thanks.